# "Post" posted by "User" association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I want to be able to associate a Post with the User that created the post.

So far I have:

```
belongs_to :user in my post.rb
```

and

```
has_many :post in my user.rb
```

I know I have to add something to my posts controller but I dont know what. I want each of my posts to have a "Posted by: (user info here)"...

Any help?   Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answers did not refer to your question about the posts controller. However, there is nothing special that you need to do in the posts controller except refer to the user which is associated through the associations you made in your model. As long as you have a valid `Post` object, your associations will trigger a query that will pull the `User` as you desire.

Comment: I dont understand why I keep getting this error "undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass". I have both belongs_to :user in my "Post" model and has_many :posts in my "User" model...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the user by doing:

```
@post.user
```

So you might have:

```
Posted By: <%= @post.user.username %>
```

where `@post` is the variable where the post exists.

You can read up on assocations in rails [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), and more specifically in your case [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-association-reference)

To answer your question, no you don't need to do anything to your controllers for this functionality to work.

Comment: Hi. Im getting undefined method `username' when i add the code. Do I have to add something to the post controller to automatically associate the post to the user that created it?

Comment: username is just a sample attribute on user. i'm not sure what your User model looks like. Use whatever attribute identifies that user(name, firstname etc).

Comment: This is my User.rb  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :activatable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, # :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :username, :image
  
  has_attached_file :image

end

Comment: So you would do @post.user.email, for example.

Comment: I have a username attribute. I know I have to add a "Created by user" to my Post Controller but I dont know exectly what to add. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can reference this association using the `user` method defined on `Post` objects by the `belongs_to`:

```
<%= post.user.name %>
```

You can read more in the [associations guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: Keep getting this error undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @ChrisBedoya: This means that the post you're accessing doesn't have a User object associated with it. You must associate a post to a user by setting the `user_id` field on that post object.

Comment: Thanks for the response but since im just learning rails I dont know where exactly to add that. The error keeps pointing me towards post_controller.rb I tried adding this @post.user_id = current_user.username
in the "show" part since thats where the error was showing but I get the same username error

Comment: @ChrisBedoya: You need to do `@post.user_id = current_user.id`, as this needs to link to the foreign_key in the users table which should be the `id` field. It should be adequately explained in the associations guide. Please let me know if you're still having difficulty or pop into the #rubyonrails channel on irc.freenode.net and ask someone in there to explain it.

Comment: now I get this error undefined method `user_id=' for #<Post:0xe618e08>
=/. Can I add that @post.user_id somewhere other than the post_contorller.rb?